# create procedure keyword won't work

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

if i  write  procedure creating code like this

```
declare
salary   number :=20000;
employee_id  number :=36325;
   procedure give_bonus(emp_id in number,bonus in number)  is
begin
dbms_output.put_line(emp_id);
dbms_output.put_line(bonus);
end;
 begin
 case
 when salary >=10000 and salary <=20000 then
 give_bonus(employee_id,1500);
 when  salary >= 20000 and salary <=40000 then
 give_bonus(employee_id,1000);
 when  salary>40000 then
 give_bonus(employee_id,500);
 else
 give_bonus(employee_id,0);
 end case ;
 end;

 it writes on output  
anonymous block completed
```

but if i write   a head of procedure    word  this one
create or replace  procedure  give_bonus ,it writes errors,please help me why?
error is   this

Error starting at line 1 in command:

```
declare
salary   number :=20000;
employee_id  number :=36325;
  create or replace  procedure give_bonus(emp_id in number,bonus in number)  is
begin
dbms_output.put_line(emp_id);
dbms_output.put_line(bonus);
end;
 begin
 case
 when salary >=10000 and salary <=20000 then
 give_bonus(employee_id,1500);
 when  salary >= 20000 and salary <=40000 then
 give_bonus(employee_id,1000);
 when  salary>40000 then
 give_bonus(employee_id,500);
 else
 give_bonus(employee_id,0);
 end case ;
 end;




Error report:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: show your exact syntax and the resulting error...

Comment: better - but still missing the CREATE OR REPLACE part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CREATE OR REPLACE` only works for top-level objects.  If you are declaring a procedure inside of another PL/SQL block, there is, by definition, nothing to replace.  You aren't creating a procedure that will exist once the anonymous block finishes so there is nothing to replace.  You're simply declaring a procedure that has the same scope as a local variable.

You could create a standalone procedure

```
create or replace  procedure give_bonus(emp_id in number,bonus in number)  
is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(emp_id);
  dbms_output.put_line(bonus);
end;
```

and then reference that procedure in your anonymous PL/SQL block

```
declare
  salary   number :=20000;
  employee_id  number :=36325;
begin
  case
  when salary >=10000 and salary <=20000 then
    give_bonus(employee_id,1500);
   when  salary >= 20000 and salary <=40000 then
     give_bonus(employee_id,1000);
   when  salary>40000 then
     give_bonus(employee_id,500);
   else
     give_bonus(employee_id,0);
  end case ;
end;
```